# Flatten list in dictionary pandas

Tags: python, json

I have following json data

```
{
    "accountId": 999998,
    "actionTime": 1528381455013,
    "additionalInformation": {
        "eS": [
            {
                "labels": [
                    "R"
                ],
                "sc": 1.0,
                "title": "Company"
            },
            {
                    "labels": [
                        "Slurpee"
                    ],
                    "sc": 1.0,
                    "title": "Product"
                }
        ]
    },
    "apiStatus": "Removed fields because of resyndication policy",
    "archived": false,
    }
```

I want to flatten data of `additionalInformation.eS`. Final columns I want in my csv (through dataframe.to_csv)is :

`label, title, accountId, actionTime`

`["R"], Comapny, 999998, 1528381455013`

`["Slurpee"], Product,  999998, 1528381455013`

I have tried:

```
data_frame = json_normalize(data, record_path=["additionalInformation"], meta=[["eS", "label"]], errors='ignore')
```

```
data_frame = json_normalize(data, record_path=["additionalInformation", "eS"], meta=["label"], errors='ignore')
```

I have referred [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238231/python-flatten-multiply-nested-dictionary-json-with-pandas) and [pandas document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) for json_normalize function

Most example covered have list of dictionary as record_path, my example has dictionary values as list.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You do not have a dataframe, you have a dictionary. How can you have `to_csv`?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried with various combination to provide record_path to json_normalize, some of them I have put now in my question

Comment: Do you want a row per label? i.e. the "R" within the labels array in your example? Or is it a row per item in the eS array?

Comment: @smj, yes I want row per item in eS array. I am editing my json to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a less verbose way to do this, but here is an option:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {
    "accountId": 999998,
    "actionTime": 1528381455013,
    "additionalInformation": {
        "eS": [{
                "labels": [
                "R"
                ],
                "sc": 1.0,
                "title": "Company"
            },
            {
                "labels": [
                    "Slurpee", "other"
                ],
                "sc": 1.0,
                "title": "Product"
            }
        ]

    },
    "apiStatus": "Removed fields because of resyndication policy"
}

ac = data['accountId']
at = data['actionTime']
r = json_normalize(data['additionalInformation'], record_path = 'eS')

r['accountId'] = ac
r['actionTime'] = at

r = r.drop('sc', axis = 1)

r
```

Gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @smj, for the simple solution. But I am in search of more generic solution, as my json will vary. I am writing a utility for the project to convert 'json to csv' for any given validated json. And I want to break all 'list of dictionary' into separate file. But here, 'list of dictionary' is part of another dictionary.

Comment: At the least, I'd say some more test examples are required to work towards a general solution.

Comment: this is the one point I am stuck, to flatten all 'list of dictionary'