# Converting dicts with nested dicts to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is an extension of 
[this question on pandas conversion from list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-dataframe)

If the dataframe includes a dict within the dict

```
[{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010}, 
{'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"}, 
{'points':90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'}, 
{'points_h1':20, 'details': {'width':10,'height:20}}]
```

So I would like to get this:

```
      month  points  points_h1  time  year  details.width  details.height
0       NaN      50        NaN  5:00  2010            NaN             NaN
1  february      25        NaN  6:00   NaN            NaN             NaN
2   january      90        NaN  9:00   NaN            NaN             NaN
3       NaN     NaN         20   NaN   NaN             10              20
```

You may have guessed that I was using `json_normalize` before and now have a `dict` but converting to `json` seems unintuitive to me here.  I have tried `list-comprehension` with `pd.concat()` before finding the answer above which almost fixed my issues (converting my column to a `list` and using `pd.DataFrame(data)` )

Comment: checkout thisone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41238357/2413548

Comment: and this one: https://www.kaggle.com/jboysen/quick-tutorial-flatten-nested-json-in-pandas/notebook